# Programmatically running advanced eBay search queries

Tags: ebay-api

On the E-Bay web site you can search for e. g. bracelets with main color being silver (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to run such query (find newest bracelets with main color silver) programmatically (via the eBay Search API)? If yes - how?

I looked at [findItemsAdvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html), but didn't find any reference to color search there.

Comment: What have you tried so far in Java and what is the eBay category ID that you are doing the search for?

Comment: @DavidT.Sadler Currently, I can run a query, which gives me X items of a certain category. The particular categories I'm interested in are e. g. bracelets or ear-rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refining searches with the Finding API is done through *Aspect Filters* which are [defined in the documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/getHistograms.html) as:

> Aspects are well-known, standardized characteristics of an item. For
>   example, "Screen Size," "Processor Type," and "Processor Speed" could
>   be aspects of Laptop PCs. Aspects can vary for different kinds of
>   items. For example, the aspects of Laptop PCs are different from those
>   of Women's Dresses (aspects for Women's Dresses might include "Sleeve
>   Style," "Dress Length," and "Size").

Performing a search is a two step process.

1. Determine what aspects are available for the category you are searching in.
2. Choose what aspects you will use and integrate them as filters in your search request.

The following examples use the [Finding Kit](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/codebase/javasdk-jaxb/FindingKitJava_1.0.zip) that eBay provide as part of their [Java SDK](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/sdks/java).

The first example shows how to obtain the aspects that are available. This is achieved via the [getHistograms](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/getHistograms.html) operation. For this example we will use the category *Jewelry & Watches > Fashion Jewelry > Rings (67681)* that is found on the US eBay site.

```
import java.util.List; 
import com.ebay.services.client.ClientConfig; 
import com.ebay.services.client.FindingServiceClientFactory; 
import com.ebay.services.finding.*; 

public class GetHistograms { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        try { 
            ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig(); 
            config.setApplicationId("<YOUR EBAY APP ID>"); 

            FindingServicePortType serviceClient = FindingServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(config); 

            GetHistogramsRequest request = new GetHistogramsRequest(); 

            request.setCategoryId("67681");

            GetHistogramsResponse result = serviceClient.getHistograms(request); 

            AspectHistogramContainer aspectHistogramContainer = result.getAspectHistogramContainer();
            List<Aspect> aspects = aspectHistogramContainer.getAspect();
            for(Aspect aspect : aspects) {
                System.out.println("* " + aspect.getName() + " *");
                List<AspectValueHistogram> values = aspect.getValueHistogram();
                for(AspectValueHistogram value : values) {
                    System.out.println(value.getValueName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { 

        } 
    } 
}
```

Each category can have multiple aspects that consist of a name, such as *Color*, and several values such as *Red*, *White*, *Blue*. An example of the output produced by this code is shown below.

- **Metal Purity**
- 10k
- 14k
- 18k
- **Main Stone**
- No Stone
- Abalone
- Agate
- **Main Color**
- Aqua
- Black
- Blue

The names and values returned from *getHistograms* can now be used as filters in the [findItemsAdvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html) operation. For the second example we will use the *Brand* and *Main Color* aspects. This example also uses the same category as the first.

```
import java.util.List; 
import com.ebay.services.client.ClientConfig; 
import com.ebay.services.client.FindingServiceClientFactory; 
import com.ebay.services.finding.*; 

public class FindItem { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        try { 
            ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig(); 
            config.setApplicationId("<YOUR EBAY APP ID>"); 

            FindingServicePortType serviceClient = FindingServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(config); 

            FindItemsAdvancedRequest request = new FindItemsAdvancedRequest(); 

            request.getCategoryId().add("67681");

            AspectFilter aspectFilter = new AspectFilter();
            aspectFilter.setAspectName("Brand");
            aspectFilter.getAspectValueName().add("Paula Abdul");
            aspectFilter.getAspectValueName().add("Tiffany");
            aspectFilter.getAspectValueName().add("Tommy Hilfiger");      
            request.getAspectFilter().add(aspectFilter);

            aspectFilter = new AspectFilter();
            aspectFilter.setAspectName("Main Color");
            aspectFilter.getAspectValueName().add("Gold");
            aspectFilter.getAspectValueName().add("Silver");
            request.getAspectFilter().add(aspectFilter);

            PaginationInput pi = new PaginationInput(); 
            pi.setEntriesPerPage(2); request.setPaginationInput(pi); 

            FindItemsAdvancedResponse result = serviceClient.findItemsAdvanced(request); 

            System.out.println("Found " + result.getSearchResult().getCount() + " items." ); 
            List<SearchItem> items = result.getSearchResult().getItem(); 

            for(SearchItem item : items) { 
                System.out.println(item.getTitle()); 
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) { 

        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably want to use [AspectFilters](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.aspectFilter). the input for that can be found in the previous query (as stated in the documentation. see [aspectHistogrammContainer](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Response.aspectHistogramContainer))

Comment: Thanks. As stated in the bounty description, if you provide a minimal working code sample for this and it works, I will award the bounty to you.

Answer (score 0):

[VariationType](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/types/VariationsType.html) appears to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks. As stated in the bounty description, if you provide a minimal working code sample for this and it works, I will award the bounty to you.